# How to make a Text widget act like marquee when the text overflows in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, text, dart, flutter, marquee

I'm looking for a way to implement Marquee style on a Text widget so that it automatically start scrolling when the text is overflowed from the screen. 
Is there a way to do it.
I've tried all the decoration modes but cant seem to find a Marquee option there.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve *exactly*, i.e. what do you mean by **"Marquee style"**.

Comment: Marquee is when the text automatically scrolls to and fro to display the whole text when it is overflowed. Its available in Android textviews

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This widget is what I came up with, and I think it serves your needs:

```
class MarqueeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Axis direction;
  final Duration animationDuration, backDuration, pauseDuration;

  const MarqueeWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    this.direction = Axis.horizontal,
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 6000),
    this.backDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    this.pauseDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarqueeWidgetState createState() => _MarqueeWidgetState();
}

class _MarqueeWidgetState extends State<MarqueeWidget> {
  late ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 50.0);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(scroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: widget.child,
      scrollDirection: widget.direction,
      controller: scrollController,
    );
  }

  void scroll(_) async {
    while (scrollController.hasClients) {
      await Future.delayed(widget.pauseDuration);
      if (scrollController.hasClients) {
        await scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: widget.animationDuration,
          curve: Curves.ease,
        );
      }
      await Future.delayed(widget.pauseDuration);
      if (scrollController.hasClients) {
        await scrollController.animateTo(
          0.0,
          duration: widget.backDuration,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Its functionality should be pretty obvious. An example implementation would look like this:

```
class FlutterMarqueeText extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterMarqueeText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FlutterMarqueeTextState createState() => _FlutterMarqueeTextState();
}

class _FlutterMarqueeTextState extends State<FlutterMarqueeText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Flutter Marquee Text"),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          child: MarqueeWidget(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Text("This text is to long to be shown in just one line"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.

Showing this error on exiting a page with this widget.

Comment: Is the MarqueeWidget inside of a scrolling container like ListView? That might crash it, because it is not rendered yet, so the ScrollController isn't attached yet.

Comment: Saved many hours for me... and did not want to use any package. This works 100% ..

Comment: Simple and elegant. I wanted to abruptly shift cursor to the last typed digit, so I replaced animateTo() with jumpTo() and removed the animation durations. Works great.

Comment: @leodriesch Kindly update it as per NULL SAFETY. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @leodriesch can you make the marquee to be continuous so that it does not pause and start again, you can make the words to that were on left to start coming from right

Comment: I don’t really do any Flutter anymore, so unfortunately I can’t. You could try yourself or ask another question here with my code in it and ask someone else to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Use The [Marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee/install) package.
and if you get any 'hasSize' Error or 'Incorrect uses of Parent Widget' Error..

Just wrap Marquee widget with container and give height and width of that container.

Comment: Can you give an example