# How to make a marquee-like animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I want to make an animation that behaves like a marquee (slides out to the right and slides in from the left with updated value) in flutter.
I also do not want to use Stack here for creating a custom animation.
Example:
[this gif shows the implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRklc.gif)

Comment: check `AnimatedSlide` (or `SlideTransition` but it is more complex)

Comment: I believe this can be achieved with simple implicit animation

Comment: You can check this out this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772543/how-to-make-a-text-widget-act-like-marquee-when-the-text-overflows-in-flutter